# Upload large file ~2G with karate

Tags: karate

I want create **api test** to upload large file (~4G), but saw

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> And multipart file file = {read: '', filename: '', contentType: ''}
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try increasing the JVM heap size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6452812/143475

but otherwise, Karate is not designed for very large files. if this is a negative test scenario, I would personally use a command line program like cURL or even the Apache HTTP client directly, and use a stream so that you don't have memory issues.

Note that it is easy to call Java code from Karate: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1128170638223364097

And it is easy to invoke a command-line program from Karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427234/143475