# Remove User-Agent header in Karate test

Tags: karate

I'm writing a test against an AWS WAF, which, among other things, checks for a missing User-Agent header.

setting configure headers = null and manually adding other required headers still generates the unwanted User-Agent header. Is there a way to suppress it? Setting it to null isn't enough.

```
Feature: 
Background:
    * url url
    * path path
    * configure headers = null
Scenario:
    Given header x-api-key = key
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Generated request:

```
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Content-Length: 189
1 > Host: blah.cloudfront.net
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.8.1)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
{blah}
```

Answer (score 1):

Karate uses the Apache HTTP client, and it looks like in newer versions, it is possible to disable the sending of this header: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1952

This requires a change in code. Feel free to raise a feature request. If you can submit a PR that would be faster.

In the meantime you can consider approaches such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56462226/143475